Putting views within a List prevents matchedGeometryEffect from animating matched geometry between states
I have a rather simple animation I am trying to achieve where the selected item in a list gets a background applied. The goal is that the grey box behind the selected item sort of morphs from previous position to the next one smoothly.
I achieved this using matchedGeometryEffect so that SwiftUI could match the background views between the two states even though technically they have a different ID path. However this effort is thwarted by List
Here is the example project. All you need to do to break the animation is surround the buttons in a List.
Why does List break this animation? Is there any way to get around that?
struct AnimationButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    var isCurrent: Bool
    var animationNamespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var backgroundView: some View {
        Color.gray
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Shape", in: animationNamespace)
    }
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(
                isCurrent ? backgroundView : nil
            )
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1.0)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    enum cases: String, CaseIterable {
        case foo = "Foo"
        case bar = "Barrrrrr"
        case bat = "Battttttttttttttt"
    }
    
    @Namespace private var animationNamespace
    @State var animatedCurrentCase: cases = .foo
    @State var currentCase: cases = .foo
    @State var isAnimating: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Without the list this animation will work
            List {
                Section {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(Array(cases.allCases.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, theCase in
                            var isCurrent: Bool { theCase == animatedCurrentCase }
                            Button {
                                isAnimating = true
                                Task { @MainActor in
                                    animatedCurrentCase = theCase
                                    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 200_000_000)
                                    currentCase = theCase
                                    isAnimating = false
                                }
                            } label: {
                                Label {
                                    Text(theCase.rawValue)
                                } icon: {
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        Text("\(index)")
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: isCurrent ? 16 + 4 : 16)
                                }
                            }
                            .disabled(isAnimating)
                            .buttonStyle(AnimationButtonStyle(isCurrent: isCurrent, animationNamespace: animationNamespace))
                            .animation(.smooth, value: animatedCurrentCase)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer().frame(height: 10)
            Text("Selected: \(currentCase.rawValue)")
                .font(.title)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}



I would suggest removing all the extra code for animating the selected case, because it's unnecessary. Specifically:

Remove the state variables animatedCurrentCase and isAnimating.
Remove the Task.
Remove the .disabled modifier.
Remove the .animation modifier.

If you then use withAnimation to perform the update inside the button closure, it works.
Other suggestions:

Use let where you can, instead of var. In particular, the properties in AnimationButtonStyle can use let.

.cornerRadius is deprecated, use .clipShape with a RoundedRectangle instead, or just put a RoundedRectangle in the background.

The.background modifier that you were using is also deprecated. Suggest re-factoring by using a trailing closure and if-statement.


Here is the updated example:
struct AnimationButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let isCurrent: Bool
    let animationNamespace: Namespace.ID

    var backgroundView: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            .fill(.gray)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Shape", in: animationNamespace)
    }

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background {
                if isCurrent {
                    backgroundView
                }
            }
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1.0)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    enum cases: String, CaseIterable {
        case foo = "Foo"
        case bar = "Barrrrrr"
        case bat = "Battttttttttttttt"
    }

    @Namespace private var animationNamespace
    @State var currentCase: cases = .foo

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(Array(cases.allCases.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, theCase in
                            let isCurrent = theCase == currentCase
                            Button {
                                withAnimation(.smooth) {
                                    currentCase = theCase
                                }
                            } label: {
                                Label {
                                    Text(theCase.rawValue)
                                } icon: {
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        Text("\(index)")
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: isCurrent ? 16 + 4 : 16)
                                }
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(
                                AnimationButtonStyle(
                                    isCurrent: isCurrent,
                                    animationNamespace: animationNamespace
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer().frame(height: 10)
            Text("Selected: \(currentCase.rawValue)")
                .font(.title)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}



When I extracted the whole VStack into a separate View, the animation just works. I can't explain exactly why this works, but this seems like it has something to do with how SwiftUI update views in a List.
In any case, it's almost always a good to divide your views up into smaller pieces.
Here I have extracted a ButtonsView, and used that in the list. I have moved 2 of the 3 states inside ButtonsView, as well as the @Namespace, but you can totally change them to @Bindings and have the parent view pass them in.
struct AnimationButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    var isCurrent: Bool
    var animationNamespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var backgroundView: some View {
        Color.gray
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Shape", in: animationNamespace)
    }
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background {
                isCurrent ? backgroundView : nil
            }
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1.0)
    }
}

struct ButtonsView: View {
    enum cases: String, CaseIterable {
        case foo = "Foo"
        case bar = "Barrrrrr"
        case bat = "Battttttttttttttt"
    }
    
    @Namespace private var animationNamespace
    @State private var animatedCurrentCase: cases = .foo
    @Binding var currentCase: cases
    @State var isAnimating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(Array(cases.allCases.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, theCase in
                var isCurrent: Bool { theCase == animatedCurrentCase }
                Button {
                    isAnimating = true
                    Task { @MainActor in
                        animatedCurrentCase = theCase
                        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 200_000_000)
                        currentCase = theCase
                        isAnimating = false
                    }
                } label: {
                    Label {
                        Text(theCase.rawValue)
                    } icon: {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("\(index)")
                        }
                        .frame(width: isCurrent ? 16 + 4 : 16)
                    }
                }
                .disabled(isAnimating)
                .buttonStyle(AnimationButtonStyle(isCurrent: isCurrent, animationNamespace: animationNamespace))
                .animation(.smooth, value: animatedCurrentCase)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            animatedCurrentCase = currentCase
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentCase: ButtonsView.cases = .bar
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    ButtonsView(currentCase: $currentCase)
                }
            }
            Spacer().frame(height: 10)
            Text("Selected: \(currentCase.rawValue)")
                .font(.title)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

